# DateTimeFormat in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to display a time string in 24 hour format and thought it would be easy in TypeScript. But I can't use the Date.toLocaleTimeString() with options for some reason. Any idea why? They are defined in a separate interface definition.

```
interface Date {
    toLocaleString(locales?: string[], options?: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions): string;
    toLocaleString(locale?: string, options?: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions): string;
}
```

The other option is to use Intl.DateTimeFormat but the constructors return a Collator?

```
var DateTimeFormat: {
    new (locales?: string[], options?: DateTimeFormatOptions): Collator;
    new (locale?: string, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions): Collator;
    (locales?: string[], options?: DateTimeFormatOptions): Collator;
```

Is it a copy paste bug in lib.d.ts (same for NumberFormat) or how am I supposed to use them?

Hopefully it's an easy fix, I'm pretty new to TypeScript so I might have missed something.

Comment: About the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` constructor: Yes, it seems that there's a bug in lib.d.ts. I reported it to the issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1911#issuecomment-77737862

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This should work...

```
var displayDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

alert(displayDate);
```

But I suspect you are trying it on something else, for example:

```
var displayDate = Date.now.toLocaleDateString(); // No!

alert(displayDate);
```

Comment: +1 as this is the answer. However about what he is doing I think he is trying `Date.toLocaleDateString` perhaps worth mentioning that interfaces are *not* instances.

Comment: Thanks Bas - I couldn't see the line of code being used that was causing the problem, but you're right `Date.toLocaleDateString()` won't work just as `Date.now...` won't.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting the data from a json string (WebApi) and using toLocaleDateString, but I think the problem was that the language in Chrome was set to English(US) (12 h clock). My OS is Swedish (24 h clock) so it seems Chrome has it's own localization settings!?

Comment: I still think the DateTimeFormat constructors are wrong. Why return a Collator when you want a DateTimeFormat?

Comment: @Fenton
How can we add some minutes or hours in the actual time ?