# How do i make the date show 12 hours instead of 24 hours in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do i make the date show 12 hours instead of 24 hours in typescript using toLocaleString? This is not a duplicate question because i'm trying to get a 12 hour format instead of 24 hour format.

```
console.log(Date().toLocaleString());
```

output shows

Thu May 18 2017 23:56:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246009/datetimeformat-in-typescript ?

Comment: This is not a typescript question, as you probably want to show it in angular template. You should take a look at angular's date pipe.

Comment: Thank you supamiu!!